# A word to indicate the ideal value between 2 other values (upper/lower)

Tags: single-word-requests

Edit: This is related to a production process where a max value cannot be exceeded, and cannot be less than the minimum. There is then an 'optimal' value, which is a term suggested in the comments by [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler)

For example, if the upper/lower limits are 3.5 and 3.0, the ideal middle value would be 3.25.

Is there a term for this 'middle value'?

Comment: For some reason the word 'nominal' came to my head but that appears to be wrong.

Comment: That's the _arithmetic mean_ (a + z) / 2, and with only two values it's also the _median_. If there's no other reason for its idealness, you can call it either one. If there are other reasons, you could refer to it as _optimum_ or _optimax_, depending.

Comment: Yes it is not simply a mean, it is related to a production process where there is an upper and lower limit, and an 'optimum' value as you have stated.

Comment: @pay nominal is correct in certain contexts. If I need to drill a pilot hole 0.202 +/- 0.001 inches, 0.202 is the [nominal dimension](http://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=163651).

Comment: @PhilSweet Oh thanks for that, so I'm not *completely* crazy! This does refer to a measurement of an object that is quite small (the end of a wire, sort of). Do you think that would still apply?

Comment: The usual circumstance is where a standard size system is in play, such as wire gage sized drill bits. So the drawing calls out a standard size, and gives the allowable tolerance. You may be able to get away with cheap stuff, or you may need precision tools, but they are the same nominal size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [target value](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/target-value.html)?

> Aimed-for output from a process, or result from a measurement.

This has the advantage of not necessarily being the arithmetic mean or median, but rather an identified "number to shoot for". In some processes there might be more tolerance below the target than above or vice versa.

Comment: This is the answer (IMHO).

Comment: I'll likely use 'target value', 'optimal', or 'nominal', thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In some profession and skills, such as metalworking and engineering, the word "tolerance" is used for the minimum and maximum values when those values are stated with respect to the desired defined value. For example, a particular dimension may be given as .250 investment with a tolerance of .0005 inches, so that the minimum value is .2495 inches, and the maximum value is .2505 inches. In such places, .250 would be the "specified value".

This is often stated as,".250 plus or minus .0005 inches", and in writing, the "plus or minus" is often replaced with a character created with a plus sign and a minus sign in the same space, with the hype of the minus sign below the.plus sign.

Comment: This is a possible option as well. I could switch the format slightly to having the focus be primarily on the *optimal* value with an upper and lower tolerance range.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **rated value**.

For example:

- *Deviations of the mains voltage from the rated value must not exceed
  the tolerance limits given in the specifications*.
- *To obtain increased capacity and efficiency, the screw compressor
  is operated at a speed greater than its rated speed*.

Answer (score 1):

How about the **sweet spot**?

From The Free Dictionary:

> **sweet spot**: an area or range that is most effective or beneficial: *an engine's sweet spot of rpm's for maximum fuel-efficiency; a store's demographic sweet spot of women in their twenties.*

With regard to your example: For a given function f(X), the *value of X between the minimum and maximum values of X* at which f(X) is optimal is the **sweet spot**. The **sweet spot** is not necessarily the arithmetic average, the geometric mean, or any other fixed function of the maximum and minimum values of X.

**Sweet spot** is perhaps most easily understood in terms of the following definition:

> The place on a bat, club, racket, or paddle where it is most effective
>   to hit a ball. [The Free Dictionary]

The optimum place is clearly somewhere between the two ends of the bat, club, racket, or paddle, and the location of that place is the **sweet spot**.  The exact location, which could be determined experimentally, will vary depending on the design of the bat, club, racket, or paddle.

Answer (score 1):

It's the *midpoint* of your target range or interval or optimal range or whatever.